# How to convert HtmlAttribute to string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to convert HtmlAttribute to string in my custom HtmlHelper but convert isn't in correct format.

```
var attributes=new {@class="myClass" , id="elId"};
string convertedAttributes=attributes.ToString();
string myHtml="<input "+convertedAttributes+" />";
return new HtmlString(myHtml);
```

How can Id do that?

Comment: try   @Html.Raw(string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be using the `System.Web.Mvc.TagBuilder` class:

```
var attributes = new { @class = "myClass", id = "elId" };

var tag = new TagBuilder("input");
tag.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(attributes));

return tag.ToString();
```